# PyQt4 - How to read QLineEdit text from within QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I created a QListWidget... The QListWidgetItem composes of a QPushButton and QLineEdit aligned inside QHBoxLayout...

Another button is created with a function to loop on QListWidgetItem(s) and read the text in each QLineEdit entry and print it...

The print shows nothing, I tried a lot of different combinations with QListWidget methods but with no hope!

[image: image here]

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

def Add_OtherItem():
    ItemOther = CustomItem()
    ItemOther.SetupItem(OthersCommandsWidget)

def ReadText_fn():
    for index in range(0,OthersCommandsWidget.count()):
        TargetItem = (OthersCommandsWidget.item(index)).text()
        print(TargetItem)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class CustomItem(object):

    def SetupItem(self, OthersCommandList):

        self.Item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        self.Item.setStatusTip("TItem")

        self.MainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.CommandLine = QtGui.QLineEdit("")

        self.DeleteButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.DeleteButton.setFixedSize(22, 22)

        self.ItemLayoutBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.ItemLayoutBox.addWidget(self.CommandLine)
        self.ItemLayoutBox.addWidget(self.DeleteButton)

        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.ItemLayoutBox)

        self.Item.setSizeHint(self.MainWidget.sizeHint())

        OthersCommandList.addItem(self.Item)
        OthersCommandList.setItemWidget(self.Item, self.MainWidget)

AppWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
AppWindow.setWindowTitle("PoC ListWidget")
AppWindow.setFixedSize(550, 550)

TabWindow = QtGui.QTabWidget(AppWindow)
TabWindow.setGeometry(8, 30, 535, 505)

WorkTAB = QtGui.QWidget()
TabWindow.addTab(WorkTAB, 'Tab.01')

OthersCommandsWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(WorkTAB)
OthersCommandsWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 40, 515, 430))

AddButton = QtGui.QPushButton(WorkTAB)
AddButton.setText("Add Item")
AddButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 8, 0, 0))
AddButton.setFixedSize(70, 22)

AddButton.clicked.connect(Add_OtherItem)

ReadButton = QtGui.QPushButton(WorkTAB)
ReadButton.setText("Read Text")
ReadButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 8, 0, 0))
ReadButton.setFixedSize(70, 22)

ReadButton.clicked.connect(ReadText_fn)

AppWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the text field of a `QLineEdit()`. To do this, you must call its `text()` property. But first, you must grab the `QLineEdit()` object.

OthersCommandsWidget is of type `QListWidget()` which has a `QListWidgetItem()` that is connected to a `QWidget()`. You can grab the `QWidget()` object using `itemWidget()`. `QWidget()` has three embedded objects: `QHBoxLayout()`, `QLineEdit()` and `QPushButton()` which can be accessed using `children()` according to the order they were added.

Change

```
TargetItem = (OthersCommandsWidget.item(index)).text()
```

To:

```
TargetItem = OthersCommandsWidget.itemWidget(OthersCommandsWidget.item(index)).children()[1].text()
```